# NodeJS - How the LOAD_SELF_REFERENCE of the "require" function works?

Tags: node.js, require, commonjs

According to [NodeJS docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together), the `require` function has a loading stage named `LOAD_SELF_REFERENCE`. It has the following pseudo-code:

```
LOAD_SELF_REFERENCE(X, START)
1. Find the closest package scope to START.
2. If no scope was found, return.
3. If the `package.json` has no "exports", return.
4. If the name in `package.json` isn't a prefix of X, throw "not found".
5. Otherwise, load the remainder of X relative to this package as if it was loaded via `LOAD_NODE_MODULES` with a name in `package.json`.
```

I assume that this algorithm resolves modules, which are nested inside the same package as the "require" caller. For instance, calling `require("a/x")` from `a/y.js`.

According to (4.), if the name in `package.json` is not a prefix of X the algorithm **should throw an error**. So I assume that the following code and the folders structure **should crash**:

```
node_modules
|-a
  |-package.json
  |-a.js
|-b
  |-package.json
  |-b.js
  |-x.js
```

where:

`node_modules/a/package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "a",
    "main": "./a",
    "exports": {
        ".": "./a"
    }
}
```

`node_modules/a/a.js`:

```js
require("b/x");
```

`node_modules/b/package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "b",
    "main": "./b",
    "exports": {
        ".": "./b",
        "./x": "x"
    }
}
```

But it somehow works.
Is this a mistake in documentation? Or I interpret the pseudo-code incorrectly?

Please, advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a [specification bug](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2699#issuecomment-628367270).